# Rapidminer - Out of memory when working on large datasets

Tags: java, out-of-memory, rapidminer

In Rapidminer v.5.3013 I want to achieve the following:

1. Read 15 million records from a database table - only one attribute but with up to 4096 characters
2. Regex replacements on that data set
3. Classification according to Naive Bayes
4. Write the result (also 15 million rows) into another table

I have the process running on RapidAnalytics with 8GB of RAM dedicated to it, though it always crashes with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Probably I have to iterate over a smaller subset of the records and **append** each part of the result to the destination table. There is a operator called "Loop Data Sets" but I couldn't find appropiate options/parameters for iterating the way I'd need it.

Has someone maybe an idea how to solve this?

Comment: At which step does the error show?

Comment: It happens at step 2. I have an "Replace (Dictionary)" operator there which as input takes on the one hand the 15 mil. records and on the other hand as dictionary input it iterates over a table with ~200 regex replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the Loop Batches operator and put Replace (Dictionary) in it, then do the append.

Comment: True, Loop Batches seems to be what I was looking for. Will try it, thanks!

Comment: From the description: This operator creates batches from the input ExampleSet and executes its subprocess on each of these batches. This can be useful for applying operators on very large data sets that are in a database.